# Is there a way in CSS, JS or JQuery that can change the color of text depending on position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am the developer of a corporate website that has a design for a page that incorporates the following:

A body background gradient, from their primary-color to white, from top to bottom, static.

A set color of headers (h1, h2, h3, etc.) is set to white.

I would like to comply with both of these, but, of course, headers don't always sit at the top of the page, especially if they are being used as sub-headers and section titles.

Does ANYONE know of a way in CSS, Javascript or jQuery that would allow the color of the text change depending on where it sits on the page, for example, at the top, the headers are white, to contrast the primary-color of the body gradient, but further down the page, the headers change to the primary-color to contrast the white of the body gradient?

Comment: Compositing is possible through new CSS standards that are not uniformly implemented across all browsers.

Comment: ^as pointed out, new things would help, but not cross browser. Your best bet is going to be to write something custom in JS/jQuery. I would suggest making an `onscroll` method that checks the stretch of the background image, then you can determine position of changes based on percentages. once you have your set pixel lines, you can change element fonts based on `$(window).scrollTop()`. it'll be very custom tho. i don't think you'll find a osfa solution

Comment: This spec seems like a terrible idea, but this guy ^ has the right idea, it would definitely have to be hooked in to your scrolling.

Comment: @Seano666, tell me about it. I'm not a big fan of the spec either. But I'm just the developer - not the designer.

Comment: @Murphy1976 I know that feeling man, good luck to you!  Chances are when someone sees this in action it will change anyway.

Comment: And this corporate website is static. It doesn't use any CMS of some sort?!

Comment: yes, it will use a CMS for SOME pages. But There has been a design change, and now this entire thread has been rendered null. I apologize for any wasted time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try css3 filter "invert". It is not really a very good result by now, but maybe you will play with it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h2").each(function() {
    var offset = $(window).scrollTop() - $(this).position().top;
    var height = $(document).height();
    var percent = (-offset * 100) / height;
    $(this).css({
      'filter': 'invert(' + percent + '%)'
    })
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #7cf1ff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7cf1ff 0%, #96a0e7 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7cf1ff 0%, #96a0e7 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7cf1ff 0%, #96a0e7 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#7cf1ff', endColorstr='#96a0e7', GradientType=0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) does something similar to what you want, though support [isn't great](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mixblendmode) (IE/Edge).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, yellow 0%, green 100%);
  font-size: 0;
  height: 200%;
}
.outer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.inner {
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
.solid {
  background-color: navy;
}
.gradient-bw {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, black 0%, white 100%);
}
.gradient-color {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, navy 0%, orange 100%);
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer solid">
  <div class="inner">
    Text!
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer gradient-bw">
  <div class="inner">
    Text!
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer gradient-color">
  <div class="inner">
    Text!
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fixed">
  Text!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for what you're looking to do?

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $(".header").addClass("activeOne");
    }        
    else {
       $(".header").removeClass("activeOne");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jdcutter/634d6vgq/129/